# How to write a racket function with using tail recursion with couple conditionals

Tags: functional-programming, conditional-statements, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I'm having a problem understanding how to set up  a racket function that has a couple conditionals for tail recursion. Normally with one conditional, I would set up the helper function and assign acc to my base case, and then call the helper function. With multiple conditionals though I'm confused on how to proceed.

Comment: I have never heard about Racket. Looks good )

Comment: Please be more specific - there is no general form for tail recursion with "a couple conditionals".

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more specifics. But in general, you can simple call any function of your choosing *in tail position*.

So with "couple of conditionals" you join them into one `cond` with several clauses, and in each clause's tail position you're free to call your function again (or any other):

```
   (cond
     (if this then do this)
     (if this then do that))
   (cond
     (if this then do the other))
```

joined together becomes

```
   (cond
     (if this then do this)
     (if this then do that)
     (if this then do the other))
```

Now `this`, `that`, and `other` in the end of each clause are each in tail position, provided the whole `cond` form is in tail position.